# Presto filter an array during aggregation

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to filter an aggregated array depending on all values associated with an `id`. The values are strings and can be of three type `all-x:y`, `x:y` and empty (here `x` and `y` are arbitrary substrings of values).

I have a few conditions:

1. If an `id` has `x:y` then the result should contain `x:y`.
2. If an `id` **always** has `all-x:y` then the resulting aggregation should have `all-x:y`
3. If an `id` **sometimes** has `all-x:y` then the resulting aggregation should have `x:y`

For example with the following

```
WITH
 my_table(id, my_values) AS (
     VALUES
         (1, ['all-a','all-b']),
         (2, ['all-c','b']),
         (3, ['a','b','c']),
         (1, ['all-a']),
         (2, []),
         (3, ['all-c']),
),
```

The result should be:

```
         (1, ['all-a','b']),
         (2, ['c','b']),
         (3, ['a','b','c']),
```

I have worked multiple hours on this but it seems like it's not feasible.

I came up with the following but it feels like it cannot work because I can check the presence of `all-x` in all arrays which would go in `<<IN ALL>>`:

```
SELECT
    id,
    SET_UNION(
    CASE 
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(my_table.values,'-',1) = 'all' THEN 
            CASE 
                WHEN <<my_table.values IN ALL>> THEN my_table.values
                ELSE REPLACE(my_table.values,'all-')
            END 
        ELSE my_table.values
    END 
    ) AS values
FROM my_table
GROUP BY 1
```

I would need to check that all arrays `values` for the specific `id` contains `all-x` and that's where I'm struggling to find a solution.
I was trying to co

After a few hours of searching how to do so I am starting to believe that it is not feasible.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```sql
WITH my_table(id, my_values) AS (
     VALUES
         (1, array['all-a','all-b']),
         (2, array['all-c','b']),
         (3, array['a','b','c']),
         (1, array['all-a']),
         (2, array[]),
         (3, array['all-c'])
),
with_group_counts AS (
    SELECT *, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) group_count  -- to see if the number of all-X occurrences match the number of rows for a given id
    FROM my_table
),
normalized AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        if(
            count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, value) = group_count AND starts_with(value, 'all-'),  -- if its an all-X value and every original row for the given id contains it ...
            value,
            if(starts_with(value, 'all-'), substr(value, 5), value)) AS extracted
    FROM with_group_counts CROSS JOIN UNNEST(with_group_counts.my_values) t(value)
)
SELECT id, array_agg(DISTINCT extracted)
FROM normalized
GROUP BY id
```

The trick is to compute the number of total rows for each id in the original table via the `count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id)` expression in the `with_group_counts` subquery. We can then use that value to determine whether a given value should be treated as an `all-x` or the `x` should be extracted. That's handled by the following expression:

```
if(
    count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, value) = group_count AND starts_with(value, 'all-'),
    value,
    if(starts_with(value, 'all-'), substr(value, 5), value))
```

For more information about window functions in Presto, check out the [documentation](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html). You can find the documentation for `UNNEST` [here](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html?highlight=unnest#unnest).